# Splitting lines from a txt file into excel columns in bash

Tags: bash

I have a text file (lines.txt) like this one:

```
ab.qq
1
2
3
cd.qq
3
4
5
ef.qq
7
8
9
```

And I'm trying to move from every 4-th row into a different column in an excel/csv file, basically what is printed with this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
split -l 4 lines.txt outsq
paste -d ' ' outsq*


ab.qq  cd.qq ef.qq
1  3  7 
2  4  8 
3  5  9
```

I would appreciate some help writting this into an excel/csv file, and also any other way that produces the result is definitely fine (without split/paste).

Comment: It is not clear if the result you already get is not satisfactory, or you need (for some strange reason) a different way to achieve the same result.

Comment: Well, what I already had didn't put the text into an excel file and also created some unwanted outsq* files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `rs` (**r**e**s**hape) utility, originally from BSD, is useful for this kind of thing.

For example:

```
$ rs -e -t 4 0 < lines.txt
ab.qq  cd.qq  ef.qq
1      3      7
2      4      8
3      5      9
```

where

- `-e` says to treat each line of input as an element
- `-t` transposes columns to rows
- `4 0` outputs 4 rows and as many columns as required

The `-c` and `-C` options respectively set the input and output separator characters - so for CSV output you can use

```
$ rs -etC, 4 0 < lines.txt
ab.qq,cd.qq,ef.qq,
1,3,7,
2,4,8,
3,5,9,
```

`rs` is available as a package of the same name from the Ubuntu `universe` repository.

---

Alternatively, you could do something like this in awk:

```
$ awk '
    {a[NR%4] = a[NR%4] == "" ? $0 : a[NR%4] "," $0} 
    END {for(i=1;i<=4;i++) print a[i%4]}
' lines.txt
ab.qq,cd.qq,ef.qq
1,3,7
2,4,8
3,5,9
```